# Using DataTemplate for infragistics XamComboEditor (WPF)

Tags: wpf, infragistics

How can I use data template for infragistics combo box?
Basically we want to display multiple columns in a combo box. These columns come from different properties of same object.

Comment: Short side note: If you want to display multiple columns in a combo editor using Infragistics, you can use the [xamMultiColumnComboEditor](https://www.infragistics.com/help/wpf/xammulticce-about). As far as I know, it was introduced in [2011](https://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/b/atanas_dyulgerov/posts/xammulticolumncomboeditor).

Answer (score 0):

Below is the sample for your problem.

```
<igDP:Field Name="MultumRoute" Label="Route" >
    <igDP:Field.Settings>
        <igDP:FieldSettings EditAsType="{x:Type Domain:MultumRoute}" EditorType="{x:Type igDE:XamComboEditor}" >
            <igDP:FieldSettings.EditorStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type igDE:XamComboEditor}">
                    <Setter Property="DisplayMemberPath" Value="Name" />
                    <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Source={StaticResource multumRouteDropDownDataSource}, Mode=OneWay}"  />
                </Style>
            </igDP:FieldSettings.EditorStyle>
        </igDP:FieldSettings>
    </igDP:Field.Settings>
</igDP:Field>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        List<CodeItem> codes = new List<CodeItem>()
        {
            new CodeItem() { Code="AAA", Description="Alpha" },
            new CodeItem() { Code="BBB", Description="Bravo" },
            new CodeItem() { Code="CCC", Description="Charlie" },
            new CodeItem() { Code="DDD", Description="Delta" },
            new CodeItem() { Code="EEE", Description="Echo" },
        };

        comboBox1.ItemsSource = codes;
```

---

```
   <igEditors:XamComboEditor IsEditable="False" Name="comboBox1" Height="23" Width="150">
        <igEditors:XamComboEditor.PreDropDownAreaTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="Code" FontWeight="Bold" Width="50" />
                    <TextBlock Text="Description" FontWeight="Bold" Width="100" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </igEditors:XamComboEditor.PreDropDownAreaTemplate>

        <igEditors:XamComboEditor.ComboBoxStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
                <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Code}" Width="50" />
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" Width="100" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </igEditors:XamComboEditor.ComboBoxStyle>
    </igEditors:XamComboEditor>
```